# Does Gauss-Bonnet theorem works with surfaces embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I was tryng to undertand if the Gauss-Bonnet theorem works for the real projective plane. I know that it does work for non orientable surfaces as long as they can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (e.g. the Mobius strip) but the real projective plane is not.

So the real question is: does it work with surfaces embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$?

By studying the problem I thing I have found a way to embed a sphere $S^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and twist it in such a way the total curvature become greater then $2\pi\chi$ but my example is quite involved and now I am not sure anymore if it is correct.

I have found very little on this on the internet.
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

The [Gauss Bonnet Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem) works even for surfaces not embedded anywhere!

The theorem is about surfaces $S$ that are endowed with a Riemann metric $$ds^2=\sum_{i,k}g_{ik}(u_1,u_2)\, du_i\, du_k\ . $$ These surfaces can be closed or have boundary curves.

Many surfaces we meet are a priori embedded in some ${\mathbb R}^n$, $n\geq2$, and they obtain their $ds^2$ from this embedding (the $E$, $F$, $G$ in the "old" books). This is the case in your examples. Another example would be the hyperbolic plane, realized as half plane $H:=\bigl\{z=x+iy\in{\mathbb C}\bigm| y>0\bigr\}$. Here the $ds^2$ is given by
$$ds^2={1\over y^2}(dx^2+dy^2)\ .$$
The $dx^2+dy^2$ is just the euclidean $ds^2$ in the plane, but we have this additional scalar factor ${1\over y^2}$.

The Gauss Bonnet Theorem has various proofs. The geodesic curvature $\kappa_g$ can be measured "within" the surface, and no embedding or surface normal is needed. See, e.g., Wilhelm Klingenberg, *A course in differential geometry*, Springer Graduate Text (1978), pp. 138–141.

Comment: the theorem is about surfaces and their metric but in all proofs I have seen it is kind of implicit that the surface is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ starting from the first proof from Gauss that used the Gauss map from the normal to the surface.
How do you define an unique normal in $\mathbb{R}^4$?
How you define the geodesic curvature on the boundaries of the surface in $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: I have posted my counterexample [counterexample](https://vixra.org/pdf/2012.0194v1.pdf)
I do not know if it is correct. In the pdf there are some typos (sorry). Ignore the bar on the x in eq (1) and the prove that the curves gamma do not intersect is actually wrong  but they do not.

Comment: Ok, Christian, thanks. I am sure you are right but my problem is that I do not know what is wrong with my [counterexample](https://vixra.org/pdf/2012.0194v2.pdf) of a sphere embedded in $\mathbb{R^4}$ for which the Gauss-Bonnet theorem does not work.
I have posted a revision 2 of the pdf with no typos at the link in this comment. I will appreciate any one that will tell me what is wrong with it.